# Off holiday time, as a Ph.D. student, would it be convenient to ask for few days rest

Tags: phd, advisor

I feel a bit tired and even exhausted of the work i am doing, would it be convenient to ask my Ph.D. advisor for few resting days to full up some energy and return more productive ?

Thanks

Comment: No. How dare you even think about it

Comment: Yea, Alright, thanks, i will ask him then.

Comment: @k99731 http://www.chemistry-blog.com/2010/06/22/something-deeply-wrong-with-chemistry/

Comment: @k99731 Yep,  Allure is right. It's not obvious this is a joke, Greta.

Comment: Can you please indicate your location? Attitude towards vacation is very different in different cultures. I'm a German advising a PhD student from India. I had to suggest rather strongly that they take at least two weeks of vacation when they were more than a year into the project.

Comment: it's pretty obvious for most of us, regardless of what they are doing in their california

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be worried about asking your advisor for vacation time. If you're hired as a research assistant, then chances are you have some number of annual leave a year. You can use those. Departments tend to be rather lax at enforcing these, and nobody counts; nobody is likely to object to "a few days" off.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, regularly spaced vacation time, however it is spent, is critical to productivity, especially in intellectual pursuits.

You should definitely take a break if you need one. Hopefully your advisor is a reasonable person and grants your request - if not, it's their fault for being insane, not yours for asking.